# SQL SSIS - For Loop Container cycling through ETL process for a Varchar ID to calculate Sales info

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, for-loop, foreach, ssis

I have a weekly process working in SSIS that calculates Sales, Orders and Year on Year comparatives to give a Territory level summary, by week for the last 2 years.

Running the process end to end takes 9 hrs and is overloading TempDB and the server.

I know the number of territories are around 200 and I want to set up the SSIS package to use a For Loop and cycle each territory in turn, rather than all at once.

Can get the package working for 1 territory but cannot set up for more than 1 territory.

Can anyone give me some advice please?

SQL 2008R2 Visual Studio.

Thanks Matt

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. This seems more like a SSRS task with a territory parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your question.

The trick to working with strings is to load them into an ADO object in an execute sql object.

select territory from [sometable]

And then use a for each and cycle through ADO Object. You will store territory into a variable on each pass and then use that variable however you need to.